# Selenium doesn't find a table

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to read this website https://www.cmegroup.com/clearing/operations-and-deliveries/accepted-trade-types/block-data.html

In that website, scrolling down there is a table:

[image]

I'm trying to read it with Selenium:

```
        // Load website
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.cmegroup.com/clearing/operations-and-deliveries/accepted-trade-types/block-data.html");            
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // Get table
        IWebElement table = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='main-content']/div/div[4]/div/div[2]"));
        //driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".block-trades-table-wrapper'"));

        // Loop table elements
        IList<IWebElement> tableRow = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
        IList<IWebElement> rowTD;
        foreach (IWebElement row in tableRow)
        {
            rowTD = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Test!");
```

After testing, I see that if I input a wrong Xpath I get an error:

[image]

Here I'm not getting any error, so the Xpath should be correct. But I'm not getting anything to read.

[image]

How can I read that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Adrian Hernando Solanas

For the first few Iteration, you won't find any record, because, if you see carefully, the first 2 `tr` does not have any `td` in it, as they are in `thead`
But when you continue Iterating, and when the code iteration comes within `tbody` you will start getting text for `td`

Also, add your code in `try - catch` block so that if a particular element is not present in any iteration, you can handle the situation as you need it.